# My bootstrap navbar toggler is not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, toggle, navbar

Please check the code to help me finding error. When I click on the toggle button it doesn't work i.e. doesn't show menu bar.

```
<body>
<!--navigation bar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-danger pl-5 fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<a class="navbar-brand " href="index.php">E-SERVICE</a>
<span class="navbar-text">our service your happiness</span>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" date-target="#myMenu">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myMenu">
 <ul  class="nav-list navbar-nav pl-5">
    <li  class="nav-item"><a  class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li  class="nav-item"><a  class="nav-link" href="#Services">Services</a></li>
    <li  class="nav-item"><a  class="nav-link" href="#Registration">Registration</a></li>
    <li  class="nav-item"><a  class="nav-link" href="#Login">Login</a></li>
    <li  class="nav-item"><a  class="nav-link" href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</nav>
```

```
<!--javascript-->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/pooper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/all.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a typo error and it shall work after you change the following.

Change

```
date-target="#myMenu"
```

to

```
data-target="#myMenu"
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <!--navigation bar-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-danger pl-5 fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="index.php">E-SERVICE</a>
      <span class="navbar-text">our service your happiness</span>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myMenu">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myMenu">
        <ul class="nav-list navbar-nav pl-5">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Services">Services</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Registration">Registration</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Login">Login</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  </nav>
```